# How to get specifc value from multiple objects and join with comma?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple objects and i want to join the specific value with comma in javascript or typescript.

Please help me to achieve this.

**Object**

```
var obj = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
];
```

**Code**

```
getCategories(params) {
  params.forEach(param => {
    this.catid.push([JSON.parse(param.country)]);
    this.api.get(`categories/${this.catid}`).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res); // Object comes from here
    })
  });
}
```

**Output Expected**

```
Afghanistan,Albania.......
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Please check the updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

and [**`Array.prototype.join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The `join()` method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
];

var res = obj.map(i => i.name).join(', ');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
];

var result = obj.map(x => x.name).join(',');

// produces "Afghanistan,Åland Islands,..."
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd9nzh

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.map and join

```
this.api.get(`categories/${this.catid}`).subscribe(res => {
    this.result = res.data.map(t => t.name).join(',');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with single iteration

```js
const obj = [
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}
];

const r = obj.reduce((res, o, i) => {
              if(i !== 0 ){
                res += ',';
              }
              res += o.name
              return res;
        },'')
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Array.from` and `join` (making use of default argument ,)

```js
var obj = [
  { name: "Afghanistan", code: "AF" },
  { name: "Åland Islands", code: "AX" },
  { name: "Albania", code: "AL" },
  { name: "Algeria", code: "DZ" }
];

const str = Array.from(obj, ({ name }) => name).join();

console.log(str);
```